# Cannot connect Edge Loop

Tags: topology

I'm sure this question has been asked and answered, but I can't find it anywhere.

I've got some fairly simple geometry on a hand I'm modelling, and I've got an edge loop, but I cannot seem to complete it. When I fill the faces, the geometry goes wild. Hotkey J is failing to connect the vertices

[image: https://imgur.com/AYuuuzx]

[image: https://imgur.com/Bb1MuUd]

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: maybe there's no face on this area, so it can't complete the face loop?

Comment: even when I fill the faces. the result of the top two quads can be seen. the 4 missing faces are all like that, they just don't link up with the face loops surrounding them